# R - reactable aggregate sum of subgroups count

Tags: r, react-table, reactable

I'm using the `reactable` package in R to display data sorted by multiple groups.
Is there a way to display the sum of all counts of all given subgroups?

Here is an example:

```
data("diamonds")
diamonds$id <- 1:nrow(diamonds)
reactable::reactable(data = diamonds[1:1000, c("cut", "color", "id")],
                     striped = TRUE,
                     highlight = TRUE,
                     bordered = TRUE,
                     showPageSizeOptions = TRUE,
                     groupBy = c("cut", "color"), 
                     columns = list(
                       id = reactable::colDef(aggregate = "count")
                     ))
```

So the first row in the ID column refers to the 7 subgroups in the `ideal` group.
Instead of showing the amount of existing subgroups I want reactable to display the sum of all subgroup counts in the first row. So `sum(67, 7, 42, 57, 46, 73, 41)`

Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: I think you need to update `reactable` package. Try running `devtools::install_github("glin/reactable")` in `Console`. You will need the `devtools` package as well. Then, `Session` -> `Restart R`, and run your code again. Your code will return desired output (ex.: Ideal id 333, Premium id 290, etc.) in `id` column/row.

Comment: Thats it. Thanks! @RadovanMiletić

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue and it was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/glin/reactable/commit/694e4ae405a5f47f9a938ca7193787a7fbe6e836). Just follow [Radovan's instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70288724/r-reactable-aggregate-sum-of-subgroups-count/70379521#comment124252345_70288724), and it will work as expected.

> Try running `devtools::install_github("glin/reactable")` in `Console`. You will need the `devtools` package as well. Then, `Session` -> `Restart R`, and run your code again.

```
> packageVersion("reactable")
[1] ‘0.2.3.9000’
```

[image]